# Do Laravel requires Composer to be installed on the server?

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I am about to develop an application using Laravel web framework. According to the documentation Composer is the dependency manager required to install the framework but my question is: Does it need to be installed on the server or just uploading the application is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading is enough.

It's very popular approach - to have a separate build server, where the project is being built as a first stage of a building process, and then this already built project is uploaded on a production server.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are also uploading the `vendor` folder and its contents with your application, then you do not need to install composer on the server.